# Ошибка util.js:109 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined после установки Torus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

Я хочу сделать авторизацию с помощью криптокошелька Torus. Установил torus, как написано в документации https://docs.tor.us/integration-builder/?b=wallet&lang=React&chain=Ethereum

После установки библиотеки и импорта Torus, как показано в документации получаю ошибку

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at node_modules/util/util.js (util.js:109)
at __require2 (chunk-UC7LELEO.js?v=db47e0f3:48)
at node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js (index.js:20)
at __require2 (chunk-UC7LELEO.js?v=db47e0f3:48)
at node_modules/web3-core/lib/index.js (index.js:22)
at __require2 (chunk-UC7LELEO.js?v=db47e0f3:48)
at node_modules/web3-eth-contract/lib/index.js (index.js:30)
at __require2 (chunk-UC7LELEO.js?v=db47e0f3:48)
at index.js:45
```

Проект написан на react, сборщик - vite
Также установлен и используется web3.js